# On Pickle Corruption

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I load a pickle using pickle.load("foo") how do I know if whats read back is corrupt or not? For example, if I'm pickling a large list using pickle.dump and kill my python process before its finished, what would the consequences then be and how should I deal with them?

Comment: One of several Error (http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.UnpicklingError) may be thrown in case the unpickling fails. You can catch the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Should the unpickling fail due to some reason, one of several [Error](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.UnpicklingError) may be thrown. You can catch the exception and handle the case appropriately.

However it is arguable that an improperly pickled or tampered data might, by chance, be unpickled properly. Resulting in invalid results. The safer way would be to append a checksum to your pickle, and verify the checksum during unpickling. Check [this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653897/if-pickling-was-interrupted-will-unpickling-necessarily-always-fail-python)

Answer (score 0):

I've just manually corrupted a pickled file. It threw an error. Presumably, if a file does not throw an error it's either the file you pickled, or it's been so carefully tampered with that it fools the pickle module. In that case, I think you're pretty much sunk.

Answer (score 0):

I have to share my experience with this error in case someone can help.

**Summary:** It is a corruption of the picke object due to different configurations of when exporting the object and when reading it

In my case, I had a notebook that was creating an ml model for me and exporting it continuously.
on the other hand there was another process that used that model.

The error was that the cluster (in my case it was Databricks services) that created the model or was different from the cluster that read the model.

**Solution**
By putting the same cluster to train the model and export it and on the other hand to import that model, it worked without problems.